# Wordpress: How to change source attribute in image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
//change color buttons
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      //change color buttons in external js-file
       $("#btn2").bind("click", function() {
        $("#btn2").attr("src","images/orange.png");
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      //change color buttons in external js-file
       $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
        $("#btn2").attr("src","images/orange.png");
       });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6E7hm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

use click

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
          //change color buttons in external js-file
           $("#btn2").click(function() {
              $(this).attr("src","images/orange.png");
           });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using wordpress then you have to use the code like this otherwise it always return error for jQuery library

```
(function($){
    //change color buttons
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        //change color buttons in external js-file
        $("#btn2").bind("click", function() {
           $(this).attr("src","images/orange.png");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

#### DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/Jq2C8/